# Drawing from the multivariate Student's t-distribution

Tags: r, random-generation

So I am trying to figure out if there is a nice decomposition for sampling from the multivariate Student's t-distribution like there is for sampling from the multivariate normal distribution:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution

There are quite a few `R` packages out there for doing this but none of them seem intuitive to me to implement.  What I am trying to accomplish it to sample from the multivariate t-distribution given that I have a specified number of degrees of freedom, a known mean and covariance matrix.

I need to be able to sample from the multivariate t-distribution because I have analytically integrated out parameters from my posterior distribution.  I.e., 
$$p(\psi|y)=\int_{R^p}\int_{R^+}p(\beta,\sigma,\psi|y)d\sigma^2d\beta$$
which after the integration results in $\psi\sim\text{Multivariate Student-t}(\mu,\Sigma,\nu)$. Since I have a closed analytical form for $\psi$, I would like to be able to sample directly from the multivariate Student t-distribution.

Comment: Have you considered using Gibbs sampling for each variable?

Comment: I'll edit my question above to incorporate your point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article on multivariate t](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution#Definition) explains that when $Y$ has a $N(0, \Sigma)$ distribution and independently $U$ has a $\chi_\nu^2$ distribution, then

$$X = \mu + \frac{Y}{\sqrt{\frac{U}{\nu}}} = \mu + Y\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{U}}$$

has a $t_\nu(\mu, \Sigma)$ distribution.

This generalizes the univariate case of Student's t, which is the ratio of a standard Normal and a (scaled) $\chi$ variate: we recognize in this formula the classic ratio of a deviation (expected to be zero) to a standard error, which is predicted by the null hypothesis of the Student t-test.

Whence realizations of $X$ ($p$-vectors) can be had from the same algebraic combination of independent realizations of $Y$ (also $p$-vectors) and $U$ (numbers), at a cost therefore of generating $p+1$ random variates for every $p$ coefficients of $X$: that's reasonably efficient.

This `R` code illustrates the case $p=2$.

```
library(MASS) # mvrnorm()
mu <- c(7, 5); sigma <- matrix(c(1, 1/2, 1/2, 1), 2); nu <- 4
n <- 4e3 # Number of draws
y <- t(t(mvrnorm(n, rep(0, length(mu)), sigma) * sqrt(nu / rchisq(n, nu))) + mu)
```

You can check that `colMeans(y)` approximates `mu`, `var(y)` approximates `sigma` multiplied by $\nu/(\nu-2)$ (an observation kindly offered by Stéphane Laurent, whose claim is justified because the variance of a [Student t distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) is $\nu/(\nu-2)$), and you can `plot(y)` to see the distribution.

[image: Scatterplot of simulated data]

Comment: @sky, do not edit someone else's answer to 'correct' it. If you think it is wrong, leave a comment, downvote, or post your own (correct) answer to set the record straight.

Comment: @sky, Thank you for catching that slip.  I have updated the image to reflect the change to the code.

Comment: It's not true that `var(y)` should approximate `sigma`. It should approximate `nu/(nu-2)*sigma`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you for noticing that!  I apologize for the oversight and will correct the statement.

Answer (score 4):

### Simulations with four different packages and plot:

```
# variance-covariance matrix :
Sigma <- matrix(rbind(c(2,1),
                      c(1,3)),
                nrow=2)
# mean 
Mu <- c(0,0)
# degrees of freedom
df <- 30
# number of simulations
nsims <- 1000
# sampling function 
sampling <- function(pkg){
  switch(pkg, 
    "mnormt" = mnormt::rmt(nsims, mean=Mu, S=Sigma, df=df),
    "mvtnorm" = mvtnorm::rmvt(nsims, sigma=Sigma, df=df) +
      matrix(rep(Mu,nsims), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE), 
    "LaplacesDemon" = LaplacesDemon::rmvt(nsims, mu=Mu, S=Sigma, df=df),
    "mixAK" = mixAK::rMVT(nsims, df=df, mu=Mu, Sigma=Sigma)$x
  )
}

# sampling
pkgs <- c("mnormt", "mvtnorm", "LaplacesDemon", "mixAK")
sims <- vapply(pkgs, 
               FUN=sampling, FUN.VALUE=matrix(0, nrow=nsims, ncol=2))

# dataframe for ggplot2
dat <- setNames(cbind(rep(pkgs,each=nsims), 
                      data.frame(do.call(rbind, plyr::alply(sims, 3)))),
                c("pkg", "x", "y"))

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
    facet_grid(.~pkg)
```

[image]

#### Note:

`mvtnorm::rmvt` allows a vector of noncentrality parameters.

### Benchmarks

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(
+   mnormt = sampling("mnormt"),
+   mvtnorm = sampling("mvtnorm"),
+   LaplacesDemon = sampling("LaplacesDemon"),
+   mixAK = sampling("mixAK"),
+   times=100
+ )
Unit: microseconds
          expr     min      lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
        mnormt 327.989 346.509 402.5122 360.5655 383.9930 3537.376   100 a  
       mvtnorm 518.982 554.235 615.9864 571.4160 604.8840 3814.493   100  b 
 LaplacesDemon 375.737 408.536 461.7511 422.5930 437.5425 3646.705   100 a  
         mixAK 875.530 911.677 938.2057 927.0720 948.2685 1237.434   100   c
```

## Update

I've just discovered the `mvnfast` package, it is the winner.

```
df <- 5
p <- 6
Mu <- rep(1, p)
Sigma <- toeplitz(p:1)
sampling <- function(pkg, nsims=1000){
  switch(pkg, 
         "mnormt" = mnormt::rmt(nsims, mean=Mu, S=Sigma, df=df), 
         "mvtnorm" = sweep(mvtnorm::rmvt(nsims, sigma=Sigma, df=df), 2, Mu, "+"), 
         "mvnfast" = mvnfast::rmvt(nsims, mu=Mu, sigma=Sigma, df=df)
  )
}

> microbenchmark(
+   mnormt = sampling("mnormt"),
+   mvtnorm = sampling("mvtnorm"),
+   mvnfast = sampling("mvnfast"),
+   times=1000
+ )
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
       mnormt  757.723  858.573 1156.3124  908.5530 1377.555  5285.759  1000
      mvtnorm 1240.112 1408.346 1956.2496 1527.7160 2253.086 98021.043  1000
      mvnfast  493.099  528.799  599.8516  554.4585  673.828  3693.114  1000
```