# Sampling from a multivariate t-distribution with different degrees of freedom for each marginal

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, degrees-of-freedom

For improved performance in Monte Carlo-based uncertainty propagation, I want to draw random numbers from a multivariate t-distribution that has different degrees of freedom $\nu_i$ for each marginal t-distribution $t(\mu_i, \Sigma, \nu_i)$, instead of supplying one (Welch-Satterthwaite approximated) $\nu$ to all marginals. **R** has no function/package for that, so what I did, along the lines of [this statsexchange entry](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68476/drawing-from-the-multivariate-students-t-distribution), is to i) create a $n \times p$ matrix of random values from a zero-centered multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N_i}(0_i, \Sigma)$ and then ii) scale each of the normal marginals by random values from a $\chi^2$ distribution $\frac{\mathcal{N}_i(0_i, \Sigma)}{\sqrt{\chi^2(\nu_i)/\nu_i}}$ with different $\nu_i$ for each column $p$ (the marginals) of the $\mathcal{N}_i$ matrix. Finally, iii) the $\mu$ vector is added.

In **R**:

```
    ## convert covariance matrix to scale matrix
    sigma <- (sigma * (df - 2))/df

    ## multivariate normal random deviates
    sims <- mvrnorm(n, mu = rep(0, length(mu)), Sigma = sigma, empirical = T)

    ## each marginal distribution scaled by each nu
    sims <- sims/sapply(df, function(x) sqrt(rchisq(n, x)/x))

    ## add mu
    return(sweep(sims, 2, mu, "+"))
```

So for instance, when I use a bivariate setup with $\mu_i = [5, 5]$, $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 0.2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\nu_i = [5, 100]$, I get the following distribution of points: 
[image]

I believe the point cloud makes sense, since $\nu = 5$ will lead to wider tails on the first (horizontal) marginal.
For calculated covariances of the created random matrix I get:

```
cov(res)
              [,1]          [,2]
[1,]  0.1998157195 -0.0001252909
[2,] -0.0001252909  0.1999400616
```

and when I fit a t-distribution on the two marginals I get

```
    > fitdistr(res[, 1], "t")
    m              s              df     
    5.0001743252   0.3461307292   4.9873844125 
    (0.0005653814) (0.0005955484) (0.0348182327)

    > fitdistr(res[, 2], "t")
    m              s              df     
    4.999976e+00   4.408239e-01   6.998011e+01 
    (6.321439e-04) (5.937948e-04) (4.428357e+00)
```

So everything looks ok to me... Question is: Have I missed something obvious? Is this the wrong approach and one has to use Copulas or Gibbs sampling? I also tested with off-diagonal covariances $\neq 0$ and results comply...

Cheers

Comment: As far asIknow a multivariate t distribution cannot have different df for each marginal